# Adding onClick event to a React Web Part

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I want to add a simple onclick function, but having trouble doing it.

I have looked online, and have tried multiple ways - such as binding it - this.update.bind(this)} within the html string, etc

What happens at the moment is the 'update' functions runs immediately at form load.

This is what my code looks like now, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { css } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

import styles from '../ReactWebPart.module.scss';
import { IReactWebPartWebPartProps } from '../IReactWebPartWebPartProps';

export interface IReactWebPartProps extends IReactWebPartWebPartProps {

}

export default class ReactWebPart extends React.Component
{
  constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.state =
    {
      //this.properties.edit = "797897"
    };

    //this.update = this.update.bind(this)
  }
  //getInitialState: function() {
  //  this.setState(this.props.dcText = "Initial state");
  //}

  public update(): any
  {
    debugger;
    alert("hello");
  }



  public render(): JSX.Element
  {

    return (


<div className={styles.reactWebPart}>
    <div className={styles.container} >
      <div className={css('ms-Grid-row ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white', styles.row)}>
        <div className='ms-Grid-col ms-u-lg10 ms-u-xl8 ms-u-xlPush2 ms-u-lgPush1'>
          <span className='ms-font-xl ms-fontColor-white'>
            Welcome to SharePoint!
          </span>
          <p className='ms-font-l ms-fontColor-white'>
            Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.
          </p>
          <p className='ms-font-l ms-fontColor-white'>
            {this.props.description}
          </p>

          <p className='ms-font-l ms-fontColor-white'>
            dcTest :: {this.props.dcText}
          </p>

        <button onclick={ () => this.update() } >Click here</button>

          <a
            className={css('ms-Button', styles.button)}
            href='https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki'
          >
            <span className='ms-Button-label' >Learn more</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't seem to have any markup returned from your render method. In your JSX (or in this case TSX) markup you just need to add the onclick and point to a function in your class, something like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { IHelloWorldWebPartProps } from '../IHelloWorldWebPartProps';

export interface IHelloWorldProps extends IHelloWorldWebPartProps {
}

export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component<IHelloWorldProps, {}> {

  constructor(props: IHelloWorldProps) {
    super(props);
    // set initial state
  }

  public button_click(): void {
    // do something here
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome to SharePoint!</h1>
         <button onClick={() => this.button_click() }>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

You could just use

```
onClick=(this.button_click()}
```

but the lambda expression (which just does a function callback) ensures that "this" is set to the control itself in the handler.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your comment.  
I have corrected the initial post HTML.  
However I can't get your extract to work either, on your second example
onClick=(this.button_click()}
it works on initial load, but the click event doesn't trigger my function.

Comment: Your updated code looks fine to me. I would try using F12 tools in the browser and step through the compiled JS to maybe figure why it is calling the handler when the page renders.

Comment: it was because i had onClick written as onclick :(

Comment: Aw, I didn't spot that either!